# Does anyone know how to fix these image and text

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
  verticalCentered: false,
  css3: false,
  sectionsColor: ['white', '#E8E8E8', '#f2f2f2', '#EC008C'],
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

    //fading out the txt of the leaving section
    $('.section').eq(index - 1).find('h1, p').fadeOut(700, 'easeInQuart');

    //fading in the text of the destination (in case it was fadedOut)
    $('.section').eq(nextIndex - 1).find('h1, p').fadeIn(700, 'easeInQuart');

    //reaching our last section? The one with our normal site?
    if (nextIndex == 4) {
      $('#arrow').hide();

      //fading out navigation bullets
      $('#pp-nav').fadeOut();

      $('#section4').find('.content').animate({
        top: '0%'
      }, 700, 'easeInQuart');
    }

    //leaving our last section? The one with our normal site?
    if (index == 4) {
      $('#arrow').show();

      //fadding in navigation bullets
      $('#pp-nav').fadeIn();

      $('#section4 .content').animate({
        top: '100%'
      }, 700, 'easeInQuart');
    }
  },
});

$('#arrow').click(function() {
  $.fn.pagepiling.moveSectionDown();
});
```

```css
#arrow{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #BBB;
    background: transparent;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    font: 36px Heiti, 'Lucida Grande', Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#arrow span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
    transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
}
#arrow:hover{
    background: #EC008C;
}
#arrow:hover span{
    top: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
 #pp-nav li .active span, .pp-slidesNav .active span {
    background: #bbb;
}
#pp-nav span, .pp-slidesNav span {
    border-color: #bbb !important;
}
 .section {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: auto 80%;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#section1 {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/aVDvkXk.jpg?1');
 background-size: cover;
}

.intro {
    position: absolute;
    20px;
 bottom: 390px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 
}
.intro h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
 position: relative;
    left: -1px;
 top: 27px;
 
}
#section4 .intro {
    color: #000;
}
/* Content page
  * --------------------------------------- */
 .header {
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.header p {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 1.7em;
  
}
.page {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 60px auto;
    background:white;
    padding: 60px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Safari<=5 Android<=3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* <=28 */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page p {
    font-style: 12px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    color: #333;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/master/jquery.pagepiling.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/master/jquery.pagepiling.min.js"></script>
<button id="arrow"> <span>↓</span>

</button>
<div id="pagepiling">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="intro">
             <h1><font color="FFFFFF">HI</font></h1>
    
   <font size="4">
            I believe in pink. I believe that  <br/>
   laughing is the best calorie 
   burner. I believe in kissing,
   kissing a lot. I believe in being strong<br/>
   when everything seems
   to be going Wrong. I believe that
   happy girls are the prettiest girls.<br/>
   I believe that tomorrow is another day and I believe in miracles<br/>
   
        </div>
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix these image and text? Because when I'm already done with my website everything works fine even in the picture and text here in my 19inch monitor but when i transfer to another 16inch monitor my text is differ from the original screen size  :(

[different monitor sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl2nL.jpg)

[here's my sample code](http://pastebin.com/TatrY4xj)

thank you for those who want to help me!

Comment: Can you provide some code in plaintext .A fiddle would be better.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `left: 620px; bottom: 390px;` in `intro` class. And add the following

```
.intro { right: 0px; max-width: 500px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youve added an absolute value to intro:left.
That means if the screen gets smaller the content is pushed over the right border. Add left:30% width:70% position:relative and display:block to the intro element and youre fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your font size from em to px, for example one below,

```
.intro h1 {
font-size: 5em to 80px; //remove 5em
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
position: relative;
left: -1px;
top: 27px;
}
```